# Collision if statement doesnt seem to work

Tags: java, if-statement, collision-detection

Basically, Im just trying out a very simple collision test for another program Im working on, but it does seem to so simple (Or maybe Im just an idiot!) Anyway, here is the code:

```
    public void run() {
    while(true){

        try {
            if(rect.rect.intersects(rect1.rect)){
                System.out.println("Test1");
                if(rect1.x == ((rect.x + rect.width)-1)){
                    System.out.println("Test2");
                rect1.x = rect.x + rect.width;
                rect1.dx = 0;

                }
            }

            rect.update();
            rect1.update();

            Thread.sleep(50);
```

The program does not get to test2!

Any help to solve this issue is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Paint component part:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    rect1.paint(g);
    rect2.paint(g);
    g.drawString(String.valueOf(rect1.x), 100, 100);
    g.drawString(String.valueOf(rect2.x+rect2.width), 100, 150);
    repaint();
}
```

Image:

[image: test]

Comment: Well perhaps `rect.rect` doesn't intersect `rect1.rect`... please edit this into a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem...

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to assume that the expression in the second if is true?

Comment: It would help if you explain what this test is meant to accomplish.

Comment: VeeArr, very good reason...  In my paintComponent method I have a drawString which monitors the rect1.x and the rect.x+rect.width, and i set the thread sleep time to 500, and sure enough at one point they where both 130

Comment: Robinson, less of a test, more of experiment/practice instead of messing up code in another program

Comment: What data type is `rect.x` or `rect.width`? If it is `float` or `double` you might have precision problems with the `==` comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the program in Eclipse (or your preferred IDE) and use its runtime debug facilities to set a breakpoint at the first if statement. Then step through and examine the values of the variables. Hopefully this will make clear why your code is failing to do what you expect.

Comment: This helped a lot, Ive not really used breakpoints before, but now i know what they are for, thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. Debugging by println is a pain. You can also set conditions on breakpoints. They are very powerful. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

How about constructing this method just for debugging convenience (unless you have a debugger):

```
public static printRectProperties(Rectangle rect, String rectangleName){
    System.out.println(rectangleName + ": x = " + rect.x + ", y = "
        + rect.y + ", width = " rect.width + ", height = " + rect.height;
}
```

Then you can simply call this method to log statistics about the rectangles prior to the execution of the if statement:

```
            if(rect.rect.intersects(rect1.rect)){
                System.out.println("Test1");
                    printRectProperties(rect, "rect");
                    printRectProperties(rect1, "rect1");
                if(rect1.x == ((rect.x + rect.width)-1)){
                    System.out.println("Test2");
```

That should make it easy to figure out why "Test2" is never printed.